# Search a directory structure and report folder present or missing?

Tags: powershell, path, subdirectory

I am looking for some help with writing the code in PowerShell to check for and report back.

I want to search `C:\MyData\MyCustomerNames` for folders `MyTests`, `MyProducts`, and `MyReturns`, and then report back `C:\MyData\MyCustomerNames\MyTests is Present` or `C:\MyData\MyCustomerNames\MyProducts is Missing`.

I know that the code `Test-Path C:\MyData\MyCustomerNames\MyProducts`could work but I also want to test for `*.xml`, `*.docx`, etc.  Plus, the only part of the path that is a variable is `MyCustomerNames`.

If you can point me to something that would work, that would be awesome, or provide an example more so than what I provided.

Please and Thank you!

Comment: Hi, check [`Get-ChildItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [`foreach`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/28/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach/) - among others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on what sodawillow recommended. Save your locations in an array, then use the `foreach` statement to run the loop for each value in the array. You can use `Get-ChildItem` in an `if` statement to search for those directories and evaluate if they exist.

```
$folders = "MyTests", "MyProducts", "MyReturns"
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    if (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\MyData\MyCustomerNames" -Filter $folder -Directory) {
        "$folder exists"
    } else {
        "$folder does not exist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was getting closer but wow did this snippet of code really help.